# HtmlUnit Setup didn't work

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a big problem with my htmlUnit Setup.
I always get a bunch of error Messages.
I think the problem is that the module earth can't be found.

This is my basic project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BMNN.png)

This is a part of the error Message:

> ======= EXCEPTION START ========
>   Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException]
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Error: Module: 'earth' not found! (https://www.google.com/uds/?file=earth&v=1#3)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:914)

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong (as far as i can see ;-) with your setup. The error you see is a script exception; means this is a javascript error thrown by the page javascript code.

If you open the page in a real browser and have a look at the developer console, you will see the same error - means the web site is buggy.
The usual browsers are ignoring this error. HtmlUnit is written for web page testing, with the default setup HtmlUnit stops javascript processing when facing the first error. If you like to force HtmlUnit to only log the error and proceed, you can do this by

```
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

But it will be better to force the page peoples to fix the js error.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you this was my error. But this doesn't work. I get the error can not resolve this method.

Comment: If you like have a look at the list of htmlunit developers, there you can find my private mail and we can discuss this in more detail via mail (and in german :-) I guess this will make things simpler.